# Registrar um valor específico a um índice e tratar os valores

Tags: python, python-3.x, lista

O número de likes é acumulativo, isto é, se a postagem tem 0 likes e recebe 5 likes, ela terá 0 + 5 =5 likes. Se logo, essa mesma postagem recebe 7 likes, terá 5 + 7 = 12 likes.

- Se a postagem original recebe entre 1 e 10 likes, então seus vizinhos
  recebem 1 like de bônus.
- Se a postagem original recebe mais de 10 likes, então seus vizinhos
  recebem a metade de likes recebidas pela postagem original.
- Erro ao atribuir likes. Se por engano há uma tentativa de atribuir likes a uma
  postagem não existente, além de mostrar uma mensagem de erro(postagem não existente), esses likes
  devem ser atribuídos à uma postagem aleatória, sem beneficiar (entregar bônus)
  aos vizinhos dessa postagem.

Já consegui atribuir likes a publicação original, mas não ao seus vizinho

Meu código até agora:

```
postagem = [5, 6, 9]

print('2) Dar likes a um post')
alternativa = int(input())

if(alternativa == 2):
     qtd_like = int(input())
     post = int(input())
     if(qtd_like >= 1) and (qtd_like <= 10):
         postagem[post] = postagem[post] + qtd_like

     if(qtd_like > 10):
         postagem[post] = postagem[post] + qtd_like
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Por "vizinho", estou assumindo que são os elementos que estão imediatamente ao lado. Por exemplo, se a lista for `[5, 6, 9, 10]`, os vizinhos do `6` são o `5` e o `9`, os vizinhos do `9` são o `6` e o `10`, o `5` só tem um vizinho (o `6`), e o `10` só tem um vizinho (o `9`).

Assumindo também que `post` é a posição do elemento na lista, basta pegar `post - 1` e `post + 1`, tomando cuidado para os casos em que ele é o primeiro ou o último elemento.

Para escolher uma postagem aleatória, basta usar o [módulo `random`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.randrange). Ficaria assim:

```
import random

postagens = [5, 6, 9]
total = len(postagens) # quantidade total de postagens
if alternativa == 2:
    qtd_like = int(input())
    post = int(input())

    if post < 0 or post >= total:
       print(f'postagem não existente: {post}')
       post = random.randrange(0, total) # escolher postagem aleatória
       print(f'escolher postagem aleatória: {post}')
       bonus = 0 # não tem bônus
    elif 1 <= qtd_like <= 10:
       bonus = 1
    elif qtd_like > 10:
       bonus = qtd_like // 2

    postagens[post] += qtd_like
    if bonus > 0:
        if post >= 1: # se não é o primeiro, dá bônus para o anterior
            postagens[post - 1] += bonus
        if post < total - 1: # se não é o último, dá bônus para o próximo
            postagens[post + 1] += bonus
```

Para o caso do bônus ser metade da quantidade de *likes*, usei a divisão inteira (`//`), que arredonda o resultado (ou seja, se tiver 13 *likes*, o bônus será de 6). Fiz assim porque não parece fazer sentido ter algo como 6,5 *likes*.

Repare que mudei o nome da lista para `postagens` (no plural), afinal, se ela vai guardar mais de uma postagem, é melhor que o nome deixe isso claro. Pode parecer "frescura", mas [dar nomes melhores ajuda muito na hora de programar](https://hackernoon.com/the-art-of-naming-variables-52f44de00aad).

Também não tratei o caso da quantidade de likes ser negativa (provavelmente não tem que fazer nada nesse caso, no máximo exibir uma mensagem de erro).